# Submit form using AJAX and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

It seems like this should be something built into jQuery without the need for more than a few lines of code, but I can't find the "simple" solution.  Say, I have an HTML form:

```
<form method="get" action="page.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="value1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="value2" />
    <select name="status">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="good">Good</option>
         <option value="bad">Bad</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

When someone changes the select field, I would like to submit the form using ajax to update the database.  I thought there would be some way to do the following without manually creating the values/attributes, just send them all, like:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $.get("page.html?" + serializeForm());
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Re: the update,

You probably don't want this to be a GET request since you're passing data to the server. But yes, that's the general idea. You're welcome :)

Comment: Here is the way i post form data to action on server http://tryconcepts.blogspot.in/2012/02/post-form-data-using-jquery-post-or.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what ended up working.

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $.get("/page.html?" + $(this).parent("form").find(":input").serialize()); 
});
```

Comment: this won't submit the value of the select though

Answer (score 146):

First give your form an `id` attribute, then use code like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var form = $('#my_awesome_form');

  form.find('select:first').change( function() {
    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr( 'action' ),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
    } );
  } );

} );
```

So this code uses `.serialize()` to pull out the relevant data from the form. It also assumes the select you care about is the first one in the form.

For future reference, the jQuery [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) are very, very good.

Comment: A very important point, that may be completely obvious to many but was definitely not so to me which is omitted here and in all the other SO posts on this subject is that in order to be successful you must ensure that the button you are using to trigger the event that causes the submit of the form via ajax IS NOT type submit! Else this will always fail. The serialize approach here is neat.

Comment: Since this code handles submitting the form on change of a select box, it doesn't matter if you have `<input type='submit' />` in the form. If you do have a submit button in the form you simply need to handle the `submit` event on the form instead and prevent the default action.  Once again the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) come to the rescue on this :)

Answer (score 31):

There is a nice [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) that allows you to send an HTML form asynchroniously.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#myForm1').ajaxForm(); 
});
```

or

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $('#myForm1').ajaxSubmit();
});
```

to submit the form immediately