# Easy jQuery/Ajax question on how to send values from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to jQuery and Ajax but I understand some simple things. However my question is what I need to add to my existing code to submit the value of the selected value of the autocomplete script I use?

Thank you.

```
$("#s").autocomplete("rpc.php", {
    width: 250,
    selectFirst: false,
    minChars: 3,
    scroll:true,
    matchContains: true,
    scrollHeight: 250
}).result(function(event, item) {
     $.ajax({
        // what to send here?

            })
});

<form method="get" action=".php">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="inputsearch">
<input id="searchform" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you make your code easier? Seperate the code to submit the form and autocomplete. It makes your code easier to understand and to maintance. So you can use the form event 'onSubmit'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.result(function(event, item) {
 $.ajax(
     {
         data: item,
         url: "insert url here",
     })
 });
```

Comment: And most likely supply `success` function as well because we usually have to do something when call succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery AJAX form submission not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722850/jquery-ajax-form-submission-not-working) shows a good example to submit a form with ajax. You have only to change the value 'post' to 'get'