# Jquery update div after form submit with same form and S_POST data

Tags: jquery

A have a page with 6 (Jquery) tabs and on each tab there is a form, i want to submit one of the forms without refreshing the whole page. When i submit a form i want to "reload" the same form in that tab, but with the $_POST data so i can use that for PHP scripting (database insert after vallidation).

I tried Jquery AJAX, but i have to define al the form ellement again to pass the POST data, is'nt there a way similar like action="" but then only for that one tab and not the whole page?

Comment: Did you try just passing `$(form).serialize()` as data in the ajax call.

Comment: @adeneo how does that look like in the ajax call? Is that a call in the "data:" part?

Comment: It would look like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425095/submit-form-using-ajax-and-jquery

Comment: Problem is that the whole page refreshes again....

Comment: Then you're submitting the form. Look at the answer below to see how you'd prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); //to prevent the page form reloading

    //provide the ajax call part after this

    return false; // to exit the function without actually submitting the form
});
```

Comment: You don't need both, to return false in jQuery is the same as preventDefault and stopPropagation.

Comment: I returned a boolean since it is unwise to write a function that returns no value, unless you're absolutely sure that you don't need one here. This return value could be used in other decision making processes.

Comment: No it can't, and no you should'nt. There's no need to return a value in an event handler like that. You're thinking of regular functions that will return undefined unless a return value is specifically given.

Comment: So if I don't specify a return value, what would it be for the function I write for this event handler?

Comment: It would be `this`, as it's a chainable jQuery method.