# staying on same page after form post

Tags: php, forms, action

and when you click send a pop up window comes up saying if it has sent successfully or not. thats all i want to happen but at the moment the pop up window comes up and in the window from where the user presses send it goes to the php page the action calls, how do i stop that window going to the php page and just have a pop up window come up?

form code:

```
<form method="post" class="contact-form" action="php/callback.php" >
                <input name="name" type="text" id="formbox" value="Name" onfocus="(this.value == 'Name') && (this.value = '')" onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Name')"/><br />
                <input name="number" type="text" id="formbox" value="Number" onfocus="(this.value == 'Number') && (this.value = '')" onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Number')"/><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" id="formbutton">
    </form>
```

php code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];

$to = "email@email.co.uk";
$subject = "Call Back Enquiry";
$message = "Hi Raymond, someone that came to your website wants you to call them back, their name is '$name' and their number is '$number'";
$from = "Your Website";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$send_contact = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if($send_contact){
echo "<script>alert('We will contact you shortly');</script>";
}
else {
echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong, try again!');</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You need javascript / ajax for that, you cannot do that in php alone.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425095/submit-form-using-ajax-and-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery with AJAX to create seamless forms that don't involve POSTing to another page.

More user-friendly popups than `alert()` can be created with UI frameworks like jQuery UI or Bootstrap.

Comment: This, and don't send back javascript from a server. OP should check out some basic AJAX tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by normal button ie. `<input type="button" />` not `submit`, without form. At `onclick` I open a new window (what about popup-blocker?), that has form inside, and in the same event procedure I send (still by Javascript) values of my fields eg. `win.getElementById[someControlName].value=document.getElementById(sourceControlName).value`. `win` is a variable of new window, while `document` is the window that is the opener. Then, if I am ready, still in the same event, I call `win.forms[0].submit()`.

I have not tested it, maybe some errors, but the main idea is clear, I hope.