# Node.js POST action keeps reloading the page / can I use ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have this node.js application in where I have a very simple feedback form. So that when the user hits the submit button it fires the POST call to the app.js file and this inserts the feedback into the table in DB.

Now, the problem is that when the form is submitted, the page starts reloading forever and appending the form action into the url, such as *www.example.com/feedback* which obviously is wrong and that path doesn't exist.

Ideally, what I would like to have is when the submit button is pressed the page will not realod maybe similar to ajax?

can anyone help please?

Code below:

app.js

```
function connect_DB() {
     connection;
     return connection;
}

app.post("/feedback", function (req, res) {
    var obj_connect_DBD = connect_DB();

    var post = {feedback: req.body.feedback};

    obj_connect_DBD.query('INSERT INTO feedback SET ?', post, function (error) {
        if (error) {

            console.log(error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('succes');

        }
    });
});
```

form in html file:

```
<form name="feedback" action="/feedback" method="POST" >
  <textarea rows="7" cols="60" id="feedback" name="feedback" required placeholder="Enter feedback..."></textarea>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">Send Feedback</button>
</form>
```

Many thanks

**FIXED**
All I did was, changing the button type to *button* instead of *submit* and then I created a function as below:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {

        var feedback = $("#feedback").val();

        $.post('/feedback/', {
            feedback: feedback
        });
});
```

No page reload anymore :)

Comment: Why not just output a page in the post route, the reason it loads forever is because nothing is returned to the browser ?

Comment: Because I don't want the page to be reloaded/refreshed once the feedback is submitted. How can I do it the AJAX way so that it is happening in the background?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425095/submit-form-using-ajax-and-jquery

Comment: fixed, see my edits :)

Comment: Then you can remove the form attributes `action="/feedback" method="POST"`