# Submit form but not unload fields

Tags: jquery, python, html, wtforms

Is it possible to submit a form and the fields of that form after they are submitted to stay with values that they had, not to be empty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) you can submit the form without leaving the page(and without erasing values), take a look at this answer [Submit form using AJAX and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425095/submit-form-using-ajax-and-jquery)

Comment: thanks @alebruck  , I tried those ways on that link, they do submit  without refreshing page, but still fields (WTForms fields)  become empty after submitting ?

Comment: @Egzona No, submitting the form will not empty fields, take a look http://jsfiddle.net/YUWB2/734/

maybe you are doing something else that is cleaning it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [JS validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) or [HTML5 form validation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp) if you don't want to use JavaScript.

I prefer the second way which is clearer, but not sure to work in every browser.